# Object has many arrays, loop through each and change some value

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has a whole host of arrays and properties. There is a property called `targetProperty` which appears in various places of the object.

I have a function where if the user clicks yes, every instance of that property needs to be reassigned to a new value.

The problem is the function that I used for assigning a new value doesn't work in this senario:

```
        reassingPropertyInObj(obj, status) {
            if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
                obj.targetProperty = status;
                for (const key in obj) {
                    this.handleExpandCollapseClick(obj[key], status);
                }
            }
        },
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Also can't use JSON.parse() or anything like that because the properties need to stay reactive for later reassignment if needed by the user.

Below is an example of one object:

```
    {
      "id": 16,
      "ref_study_id": "3412333",
      "title": "SomePersonNameOne",
      "capabilities_available": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "name": "Clinical Data",
        },
        {
          "id": 538,
          "name": "RK's Capability",
        }
      ],
      "capabilities_impacted": [],
      "businessImpact": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Medium"
      },
      "sites_impacted": [],
      "sites_available": []
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "ref_study_id": "123124",
      "title": null,
      "capabilities_available": [
        {
          "id": 37,
          "name": "Clinical Site Experience,
        },
        {
          "id": 41,
          "name": "Experience",
        }
      ],
      "capabilities_impacted": [
        {
          "id": 37,
          "name": "Information Exchange",
          "is_study_level": false,
          "businessImpact": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Medium"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "IT/Data Experience",
          "is_study_level": false,
          "businessImpact": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Medium"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 34,
          "name": "Mgmt & Storage",
          "is_study_level": false,
          "businessImpact": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Minor"
          }
        }
      ],
      "businessImpact": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Medium"
      },
      "sites_impacted": [],
      "sites_available": []
    },
```

And the property in question is `businessImpact`. As you can see it appears by itself as a property and inside array (and sometimes those arrays of arrays of their own).

I setup a function like:

```
                    arrayOfProperties.forEach((property) => { 
                           obj[property].forEach((o) => { 
                               o.businessImpact = newVal; 
                           });
                        });
```

But of course it doesn't go deep enough.

Comment: Missing a `"` after `"Clinical Site Experience`. Just to let you know in case that error exists in your real code.

Comment: No that was just me cleaning this up. The object comes back from an API